# How to post new messages in every function call?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

```
private bool displayed;
private void PostMessage()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
        {
            if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]) && !displayed)
            {
                displayed = true;
                lineToPost = ScrollLabel._lines[i];
                PostFacebookWall(LongaccessToken, lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "נשלח באופן אוטומטי כניסיון דרך תוכנה");
                numberofposts += 1;
                label7.Text = numberofposts.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And calling this method in a timer_tick event

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 10)
    {
        PostMessage();
    }
}
```

It posting same line, but need to send different line/s that contain the words unused, it can be the same word but in a different line, since the variable `displayed` is true it will send only one line once.

The variable WordsList.words is string array, _lines is string array , lineToPost is string and which are having values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Listfor this problem.

Instead if `_lines` of type string array use

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>> _lines;
```

And the condition should be

```
if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Key.Contains(WordsList.words[x]) && !_lines[i].Value)
{
    _lines[i].Value = true;
    ...
    ...
}
```